# Going crazy; how to setOnclickListener from within adapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter

So I used to have setOnItemClickListener in my main activity like this:

```
overviewEventListPending.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        final OverviewEvent clickedOverviewEvent  = (OverviewEvent) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, OverviewEventDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("overViewEventId", clickedOverviewEvent.uuid.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

This worked all fine, until my collegue started using BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter as a base class. So I now want to implement the listener within the adapter like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (type) {
       case TYPE_ITEM:
            OverviewEvent rowItem = (OverviewEvent) getItem(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_event, null);

            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_description);
            holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_amount);
            holder.actionDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_date);
            holder.counterparty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_counterparty);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_avatar);

            holder.description.setText(rowItem.eventDescription);
            holder.amount.setText(rowItem.getDisplayAmount());
            holder.amount.setTextColor(rowItem.getAmountColor());
            holder.actionDate.setText(rowItem.getDisplayDate());
            holder.counterparty.setText(rowItem.creditorDisplayName);
            ImageAdapter image = new ImageAdapter(context);

            try {
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(image.getImage(rowItem.avatarId).getBitmap());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to set overviewEvent avatar", e);
           }
           convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewEventDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("overViewEventId", uuid.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            break;
        case TYPE_DIVIDER:
            OverviewEventDivider divider = (OverviewEventDivider) getItem(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_event_divider, null);
            TextView dividerTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overview_event_divider);
            dividerTitle.setText(divider.title);
            break;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

It now complains that `The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<OverviewEventDetails>) is undefined`.

Does anybody know how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Just FYI, you can still use `setOnItemClickListener` with a BaseAdapter.

Comment: Just FYI, @Geobits has a point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewEventDetails.class);
```

In the line above you are giving "this" from adapter so you are actually giving the adapter object, but in real it needs "Activity" context/object. So you should get the Context from actvity with your constructor and use it on the intent creation like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OverviewEventDetails.class);
```

Comment: or simply `v.getContext()`

Comment: Awesome! One last thing: it now says that The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener() {}. Any idea how I could solve that..?

Comment: the same way ... `v.getContext().startActivity(...)`